# Is the square wave a function?

Tags: functions

This might be a silly question but - is the square wave a function? I ask because it clearly fails the vertical line test, but I haven't been able to find sources that say if it is or isn't one.

Comment: Please provide some more details like links, your own works some definitions, etc.

Comment: This is the square wave: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_wave

Comment: You should write the definition you are using in the question statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to define a square wave so it is a function is something like
$$f(x)=\begin {cases} 1&2k \le x \lt 2k+1\\0&2k+1 \le x \lt 2k+2 \end {cases}$$
for $k$ an integer.  This passes the vertical line test-for each $x \in \Bbb R$ there is exactly one value for $f(x)$

If we draw the vertical lines as part of the graph it either does not represent a function as you say, or it represents an approximation to the square wave and the "vertical lines" are not quite vertical.  The real square wave function is not continuous at the integers, but it is a fine function.